# How return value range in React?

Tags: reactjs

Add a midnight. When changing the slider, display its value on the page.

```js
range(e) {
    this.setState({ rangeText: e.target.value });
}

<input
    onInput={this.range}
    type="range"
/>

<p>{this.rangeText}</p>
```

Comment: It should be `<p>{this.state.rangeText}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're changing the `rangeText` state value, but you're not referencing it correctly in your `render()` function.

Below code should be running without problems:

```
class TestComponent extends React.Component {

constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    rangeText: undefined
  };

  this.range = this.range.bind(this);
}

range(e) {
    this.setState({ rangeText: e.target.value });
}

render() {
  return (
     <input
      onInput={this.range}
      type="range"
     />
     <p>{this.state.rangeText}</p>
  );
 }
}
```